# expected identifier (in C)

Tags: c, program-entry-point, do-while, cs50, function-definition

I am currently doing CS50 introduction to computer science:
I started this code (written in C) where I have to code a pyramid based on what the user writes.

**Here is my code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cs50.h>

int main(void);

int n;

do

{

    n = get_int("Positive Number: \n");

}

while (n > 0 || n < 9);
```

**Here is the error displayed by my terminal:**

> ```
> mario.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('
> do
> ^
> mario.c:10:1: error: expected identifier or '('
> while (n > 0 || n < 9);
> ^
> 2 errors generated.
> <builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
> make: *** [mario] Error 1
> ```

Can someone please help?
William

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but have a close look at your condtion `n > 0 || n < 9`. Hint: this condition is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed a semicolon after the declaration of the function main

```
int main(void);
            ^^^^
```

Remove it and enclose the body of main in braces

```
int main(void)
{
    //...
}
```

Also it seems the condition of the do-while statement

```
do

{

    n = get_int("Positive Number: \n");

}

while (n > 0 || n < 9);
```

is incorrect. I suspect that you want to repeat the loop if the entered value of `n` is not positive or is greater than or equal to `9`. In this case the condition should look like

```
do
{
    n = get_int("Positive Number: \n");
} while ( !( n > 0 && n < 9 ) );
```

Comment: thanks vlad but I am trying to create a loop where the user has to enter a positive number inclusive 1 to 8. Can you tell me how I can do that ?

Comment: @William I suppose you want to continue the loop while the user is not entering a positive number or a number less than 9. If so see my answer where I showed how the condition of the loop should be written.

Comment: thanks vald I have managed to fix my problem although I used || (OR) instead of && (AND)

Answer (score 8):

Look at your `main()`. You're not writing the definition; you're just declaring the main function prototype.  Fix it by adding braces:

```
int main(void) {
  .
  .
  .
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to code on function main()